# What is the purpose of uint256(-1)

Tags: solidity

I've seen a contract that stores `-1` as an unsigned integer.

`uint256 can = allowed ? uint256(-1) : 0;`

Can anyone explain the benefit of this over something like:

`uint256 can = allowed ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By 2s-complement, `uint256(-1)` is equal to the maximum value of `uint256`.

So it's essentially a shorter way to write `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

For `bool can`, your wondering would be correct (i.e., `allowed ? true : false` would suffice).

But since `uint256 can` is used, the answer to your question depends on what it is used for...

Comment: OK, that's clarified a lot. Digging further, this variable is used to set the spending allowance. I was looking at it as if it were setting a boolean in some way.

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, if it was setting a boolean, then most likely no code was needed to begin with, since that boolean is already given as input, right? I mean, what else could `allowed` be? But you're right about the name `can` implying of a boolean variable; it's probably just a bad naming-choice.

Answer (score 2):

uint256(-1) is a trick to gives the maximum uint256 value.

Comment: Note that it was already mentioned a few minutes ago in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Use `type(uint256).max` for better readability. Supports Solidity >= 0.6.8

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is another REAL purpose

Tests are passing:

`for (uint256 i = pendingDepositsLength - 1; i != uint256(-1); i--) {`

Test are failing:

`for (uint256 i = pendingDepositsLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {`

#### Explanation

`i--` causes underflow and `i` becomes a really large number.

`uint256(-1)` solves that. Clever use case, not sure about readability.

I wanted to refactor but the failing tests raised the alarm.